# Line-Break in Safari causing problems

Tags: html, css, safari

I just signed up for that one specific question and hope you can help :)

Our [website](https://tecwriter.de) has a title-area where the title has grey background.

The issue here occurs only on safari: When there occurs a line-break (due to a longer headline), safari still renders the background-color with the width of the previous line-lenght and adds an additional line. It works fine on **Chrome**, **Firefox** and others except on **Safari** it looks like this.

HTML

```
<div class="so-widget-sow-headline so-widget-sow-headline-default- 9cab5f85f9f7"><div class="sow-headline-container ">
 <h1 class="sow-headline"> E-Learning-Erstellung </h1>                   
 <div class="decoration">
  <div class="decoration-inside"></div>
 </div>
 <h2 class="sow-sub-headline">Individuell. Von A-Z.</h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.header-img-area h2.sow-headline, .header-img-area h1.sow-sub-headline, .header-img-area h2.sow-sub-headline, .header-img-area h3.sow-sub-headline {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0 !important;
    background-color: rgba(78, 78, 78, 0.9);
    box-shadow: -10px 0px 0 rgba(78, 78, 78, 0.9), 10px 0px 0 rgba(78, 78, 78, 0.9);
    -webkit-box-shadow: -10px 0px 0 rgba(78, 78, 78, 0.9), 10px 0px 0 rgba(78, 78, 78, 0.9);
    -moz-box-shadow: -10px 0px 0 rgba(78, 78, 78, 0.9), 10px 0px 0 rgba(78, 78, 78, 0.9);
    box-decoration-break: clone;
```

It should behave like you would expected: When there occurs a line-break it should also break the background-color.

Answer (score 3):

I solved it using `white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right you want the background colour not to cover the whole line, but just as long as your text is? That is due to your h1 being a block element. By applying a "display: inline" style it should apply the background only to the width of your text.

```
 <h1 class="sow-headline" style="display: inline"> E-Learning-Erstellung</h1>                   
 <div class="decoration">
  <div class="decoration-inside"></div>
 </div>
 <h2 class="sow-sub-headline">Individuell. Von A-Z.</h2>
</div>
```

Also in case you need you can change your line height so that it does not cover the below line.

Hope it helps, in case I understood wrong feel free to share some printscreens!

Comment: Thank you for you response. 

Yes thats exactly what I am looking to do. The h1/h2 is already set to a display:inline and it works as indented on chrome and firefox but unfortunalely not on safari

Comment: Feel free to look at those screenprints to understand whats the issue 
[link](https://cloud.tecwriter.de/index.php/s/toaQrMY8K4bFHcM)